# Saving html to 'manage files'

Tags: desire2learn

I have an external editable html file (using blocks of contentEditable="true") linked in the table of contents. Using Valence, could I save the edited contents of that file to the 'Manage Files' section of that course? Started reading through the Valence docs, but thought i'd ask here before wasting too much time there. Thanks, S

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what exactly your meaning. Currently, the only direct access that you have to course content through the Valence Learning Framework APIs is via the course content module-topic structure. The URL property associated with an uploaded topic file situates it within the "manage files" tree, and you can use this property to fetch the contents of a topic from the structure.

There are no API calls to in-place update the contents of a topic file; to update it, you must fetch it, delete the topic, then re-upload the updated file content to a new topic node. This may leave behind the previous topic file, unlinked from the content structure.

The current course content API design proceeds from the user scenario of roughing out the framework for a new course's content, and not necessarily maintaining or changing that course content over time. Enhancement to the course content APIs to more comfortably accomodate additional use-cases is on the roadmap, but is not currently fully scheduled and fleshed out.

Comment: So currently there's no way to have a button on an html page (that is a course file) that would gather data on that page and then use Valence to save a json file to the course files area?

Comment: If you're willing to have the new data be a new topic file, then you may be able to do what you suggest, but you cannot really update the contents of a content file and not affect the content structure.